# Possible to install miniconda (or conda) into an existing python3 virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, conda, miniconda, python-venv

I sometimes have to work on a large linux server shared by multiple developers, so I have a python3 virtual environment on that machine for all my python work, so that I can control the versions of packages I am using independent of the other developers on the machine (and furthermore I can install whatever python packages I want in my environment because I otherwise don't have root or sys admin access to the machine).

The question is, is it possible for me to install miniconda or conda **into that virtual environment?**

Thanks.

Comment: I have trouble seeing the value in hacking an existing non-Conda virtual env to acquire Conda functionality: 1) Miniconda already is installable without elevated permissions; 2) the env containing `conda` package (usually **base**) should be kept stable, i.e., one is best off not using it for development - instead create per-project envs. I think you'd be fine with a standard Miniconda install for your user only.

Comment: @merv Thanks.  I'll give a standard Miniconda install a try and see how it works.